# jQuery addClass and removeClass issue

Tags: jquery

Im showing and positioning a `<span>` based on a rollover event. The rollover is also triggering an opacity change. Everything is working well, except the opacity class is being removed when the hidden element is visible and you scroll over this element.

So in the fiddle below, if you rollover the 'Hello' element, the background image opacity is removed.

I cannot change the markup, so the jQuery will need to do all of the lifting.

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/W3wEd/

```
$('.campaign-1').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).addClass('campaign-hover');
    updateHover();
});
$('.campaign-1').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('.campaign-hover').removeClass('campaign-hover');
    updateHover();
});
$('.cta').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).addClass('cta-hover');
    updateHover();
});
$('.cta').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('cta-hover');
    updateHover();
});

function updateHover() {
 if ($('.campaign-1').hasClass('campaign-hover') || $('.cta').hasClass('cta-hover'))
   {
    $('.cta').show();        
 } else {
    $('.cta').hide();
 }

 };
```

Comment: If what you're trying to achieve involves just hover in/out, why not to do it just with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** The cleanest solution is CSS.  If the markup cannot change, you can easily use jQuery to dynamically alter the markup, if that is acceptable.  See: http://jsfiddle.net/W3wEd/6/.

```
.someClass:hover .someDescendentClass { /* set some style */ }
```

Cheers,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateHover() {
    if ($('.campaign-1').hasClass('campaign-hover') || $('.cta').hasClass('cta-hover'))
    {
        $('.cta').show();
        $('.campaign-1').find('a').css('opactiy','1');        
    } else {
        $('.cta').hide();
        $('.campaign-1').find('a').css('opactiy','0.5'); 
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the hover class from the background on the leave event which gets fired when the mouse is moved over the span. If the span would be a child element of the section this would not happen (btw. that is exactly the difference between `mouse-out` and `mouse-leave`, see explanation [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/)).

I would suggest to move the span within the section using js: http://jsfiddle.net/W3wEd/7/

If you can't do that you would have to manually correct the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/W3wEd/8/

Answer (score 0):

As you're happy to do anything using jQuery and can't change the markup (at least not in the exactly way - edit it), that's a way.

You just move the `.cta` element into the `.campaign-1` element:

**jQuery:**

```
$(".cta").appendTo(".campaign-1");

$('.campaign-1').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).addClass('campaign-hover');
    $('.cta').show();
});

$('.campaign-1').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('.campaign-hover').removeClass('campaign-hover');
    $('.cta').hide();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.campaign-1 {
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W3wEd/9/